# Has anyone embedded C# code in a SharePoint Content Query XSL?

Tags: development, xslt, content-query-web-part

Has any ever tried calling an embedded C# function from within content query XSL?

Contrived example:

The exception in the SharePoint log is:

System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Execution of scripts was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableScript property to enable it.

Given that I only have "control" of the XSL and not the underlying code for the web part, am I simply out of luck or is there some way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure some have tried but failed miserably as embedding the code directly in the XSL is highly unwanted. Not even javascript is recommended embedding unless it is `function`references only.

Changes made in the XSL will require you to add something to the templates. Templates are applied to items present in the CQWP. So if you have 5 items, the code will be added 5 times to the page as it gets applied to every single item.

If you have some custom C# code that needs to be executed at whatever point in the CQWP lifecycle, it is recommended that you create a custom web part inheriting the `ContentByQueryWebPart` class.